# Custom Scope in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

Micronauters,

I'm trying to implement a custom scope for my micronaut application to handle multi-tenancy.  I would like to inject tenancy information into a context and be able to reference that context within a method using something like a MethodInterceptor.  There isn't much documentation in the form of examples out there on how I would do this.  Has anyone come across this use case?  It would seem to be pretty common among multi-tenant applications.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No reason why this wouldn't be possible. You would need to implement the `CustomScope` interface similar to how the `@CurrentSession` works for Hibernate. See https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/blob/master/configurations/hibernate-jpa/src/main/java/io/micronaut/configuration/hibernate/jpa/scope/CurrentSessionScope.java

The beans would have to use `ServerRequestContext` probably to look up the request and resolve the tenant.